# I have no idea what my old shirt says. Can anyone help?

Tags: translation

I have owned [this old RVCA shirt](https://twitter.com/#!/samuelbrand/status/175314158353522688/photo/1) for nearly a decade. I have never had any clue what it means, though I suspect it is offensive or awkward (as that is what I would put on a shirt if I knew an ignorant teen was going to purchase it). Any genuine help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since they are clipped, I can only guess.

- The First line is probably `渋谷道玄坂に`, with the first character clipped. Means "at Shibuya Doogenzaka". It's a place known for young people gathering.
- The second line is clipped, and I can only reconstruct `の快楽探し` part. I don't know what was clipped off on the left side. On the right side, `し` is probably clipped. It means "finding pleasure of ..." (... part is clipped).
- There is something between V and C, but I cannot tell. The three characters I can recognize are `ル`, `メ`, and `素`.

Comment: Maybe 噂 before の快楽? Looks like the right half of 噂 or 樽.

Comment: @Chocolate Likely.